# Get count of wikiPageWikiLink associated with every entity from dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to get entities that have a lat/long and startDate associated with them as well as the count of `wikiPageWikiLink`. I'm using the following query and seeing two problems:

1. The count isn't appearing correctly
2. Spurious lat/longs are appearing in the results

```
SELECT ?label ?subject  ?lat ?long ?startDate (count(?o) as ?num) WHERE {
  ?subject geo:lat ?lat.
  ?subject geo:long ?long.
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label.
  ?subject dbo:startDate ?startDate.
  ?subject dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?o
  FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
}
GROUP BY ?label ?o ?subject ?lat ?long ?startDate ?num
LIMIT 1000
```

Example result with the query:

```
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   32.7063 -117.162    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   32.7063 -117.162    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   32.7063 -117.162    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   32.7063 -117.162    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   32.7063 -117.162    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   -0.00170132 -1.31025e-33    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   -0.00170132 -5.90549e+15    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   -0.00170132 -4.56863e+15    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   -0.00170132 -7.06605e+14    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   -0.00170132 -2.34326e-17    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  1
```

Expected result:

```
"Asia Pop Comic Convention"@en  :Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention [http]   32.7063 -117.162    "2015-09-17"^^xsd:date  10
```

where 10 is the number of `wikiPageWikiLink` associated with the entity. Please help.

Comment: the count doesn'r appear because you're grouping by `?o` which doesn't make sense

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that your current posted query doesn't work at all, at least not on official DBpedia endpoint. Do you understand the purpose of `GROUP BY`? I mean, why would you group by `?num`?

Comment: `SELECT (sample(?_label) as ?label) ?subject  (sample(?_lat) as ?lat) (sample(?_long) as ?long) ?startDate (count(distinct ?o) as ?num) WHERE {
VALUES ?subject {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Asia_Pop_Comic_Convention>}
  ?subject geo:lat ?_lat.
  ?subject geo:long ?_long.
  ?subject rdfs:label ?_label.
  ?subject dbo:startDate ?startDate.
  ?subject dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?o
  FILTER (lang(?_label) = 'en')
}
GROUP BY ?subject ?startDate
LIMIT 1000` - remove the `VALUES` clause to omit the debugging

Comment: Thanks for your help. The query indeed works on the public endpoint and that's how I got that result. You are right, ```$num``` in GROUP BY doesn't make sense. Thanks again!